# How to use find command in unix to search files only in a directory not in subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I want to list all the files or specific files based on the pattern only from the directory which i give and not in its descend or sub directories. I tried  of using -maxdepth 1 / -depth 1 / -prune options. when using -maxdepth option, it says "maxdepth is not a valid option" and when using -depth option, it says "conjunction is missing".

For example,

#1

```
find /directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -ls
```

#2

```
find /directory/ -depth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -ls
```

#3

```
find . \( -name .dir1 -prune -o -name '*.txt' \) -print
```

I am not able to use any of these options. Please correct me if anything is wrong with my script/let me know how to get files only from the directory which i give and not from its sub directories. I actually almost tried many options apart from the above examples but still i am stuck up with this. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: `-depth` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is simply `ls`. Or even `echo`. Just to be sure, you do have something else to put in that `find`, don't you?

Comment: 1. `-maxdepth` is not available in all versions of `find`. Which `find` utility are you using? 2. As said in a comment above, `-depth` doesn't take arguments (it only switches on the depth-first search mode of `find`). 3. more likely: `find . \! -name '.' -prune -false -o -name '*.txt'`. Now, this would be nearly the same as the much simpler: `printf '%s\n' *.txt`.

Comment: The `-maxdepth` option is not specified by POSIX, but `-prune` is.  If you have a non-POSIX `find` then it's critically important that we know exactly which `find` it is.  GNU `find` (the usual one in Linux distros) and OS X's `find` (inherited from BSD) both support both options, though.

Comment: If you do have `-prune` after all, though, then you should be able to do `find ./* -name '*.txt' -prune`.  Note the `./*` argument instead of simply `.` -- that provides the correct scope for `-prune`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't really agree with your `./*` to _provide the correct scope for `-prune`._

Comment: Note that there *are* some versions of `find` which support a `-depth n` test (or "primary", in the language of some manpages). For instance, the OS X `find` included with Yosemite documents it as "True if the depth of the file relative to the starting point of the traversal is _n_." Given such a `find`, `find . -depth 2 -prune -o -depth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print` should do what you want. (I include the `-prune` to prevent it from recursing into any child directories, which could be very expensive if they are deep and/or contain many files.)

Comment: Thanks guys.. actually now i am able to get the results only from the current directory using the below command with filter like *. txt or *.csv
find ./* -prune
but before that i need to change the directory as current directory to execute the above command. 
Another problem is i want to list out the files between 2 dates. I used -newer and touch commands but still struggling to get the results which i expected.